# Union with tuples Python

Tags: python, tuples, union

```
import itertools

list_with_tuples=[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
pairs = itertools.combinations(list_with_tuples, 2)
for pair in pairs:
   print(pair)
```

so the result of pairs is :

```
 ((1,),(2,)) ,

 ((1,),(3)) ,

 ((2,),(3,))
```

How I can union them? 
After union I want to do a dictionary like:

```
di={ (1,2): value1, (1,3): value2, (2,3): value3 }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is `list_with_tuples` guaranteed to consist of singletons? You might just want to flatten it to a list of values (`combinations([v[0] for v in list_with_tuples], 2)`.

Answer (score 11):

One way to "union" tuples in python is to simply add them:

```
>>> (1,) + (2,)
(1, 2)
```

So you can modify your example to add:

```
import itertools

list_with_tuples=[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
pairs = itertools.combinations(list_with_tuples, 2)
for left, right in pairs:
     print(left + right)
```

Outputs:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
```

---

If you need to add `n` tuples, rather than just 2 of them, you can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and specify an initial value of the empty tuple `()` as the second argument.

Alternatively, as Kevin mentioned in the comments, you can build a new tuple by consuming the output of an [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), which will likely be more efficient if `n` is large.

Comment: `tuple(itertools.chain(*pair))`

Comment: For example if i have (1,2) and (2,3). How can I do this (1,2,3)?

Comment: @nancy: Turn them into sets (with `set()`) and use the `|` operator to union them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` comprehension to do this for you. Iterate over the `itertools.combinations`, index out the values from the `tuple`, then create your new `tuple` as the key and add them for the value.

```
>>> {(i[0],j[0]) : i[0] + j[0] for i,j in itertools.combinations(list_with_tuples, 2)}
{(1, 2): 3, (1, 3): 4, (2, 3): 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the elements into a single tuple:

```
from itertools import chain,combinations
list_with_tuples=[(1,), (2,), (3,)]


di =  {tuple(chain.from_iterable(comb)):"value" for comb in combinations(list_with_tuples, 2)}

print(di)
{(1, 2): 'value', (1, 3): 'value', (2, 3): 'value'}
```

It will work for any length combinations.

If you have a another container that has the values you can zip:

```
from itertools import chain,combinations
list_with_tuples=[(1,), (2,), (3,)]

values = [1,2,3]
di = {tuple(chain.from_iterable(comb)): val for comb,val in zip(combinations(list_with_tuples, 2),values)}

print(di)
{(1, 2): 1, (1, 3): 2, (2, 3): 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join iterable objects such as tuples and lists together using `itertools.chain()`:

```
list_with_tuples=[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
pairs = itertools.combinations(list_with_tuples, 2)
for pair in pairs:
    print(tuple(itertools.chain(*pair)))
```

This also has the advantage of being lazy, so you can iterate over the chain one element at a time instead of making a full tuple out of it, if that's what you need.  If `pair` is also a lazy iterator, you probably want to use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) instead of the star operator.